Error on editing PermissionSet with Salesforce API Integration
I have a permission set with the Salesforce API Integration license assigned to a user with a profile having the new Salesforce Integration license. On editing the permission set i get the error
Can't save permission set PSetName, which is assigned to a user with user license Salesforce Integration. This permission set contains an object that requires a license. Before continuing, assign the user to the related permission set license.
If I unassign the user from the permission set, I am able to edit and save the PermissionSet and then i can assign the user back too.
This seems like a salesforce bug to me since the license mismatch is expected, because there is no Salesforce API Integration license profile. It is called Salesforce Integration license. Is there any other workaround for this?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.integration_user.htm&type=5
